# Can we create a recursive model in keras?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, computer-vision

I have models to make in keras. The output of one model has to be fed as input to other models.

Input -> say a batch of 64 X 64 images
First model outputs -> three outputs , splits some of the input images of the batch to 32 X 32, 64 X 32 and 64 X 16.

Each of these images of different sizes will be input to three different models which will further split them. This will continue six times in a recursive fashion.

See the pic for better understanding:[Click to see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AYRR7.jpg)

There are 6 stages in each stage there are three choices from the parent model.
**In this way a ternary tree structure of models is formed.**
Each model has its own loss and optimizers.

How to implement such a model during training ? Should we use recursion ? Is recursion allowed in model training in such a manner in keras?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will the sizes/number change during training? Or will you define the setup and keep it like that? If you are keeping it the same throughout, but just changing it to test different model setups, you can easily create a function that generates the model tree. For example

```
def create_model(tree_depth):
    models = []
    for i in range(tree_depth):
        model = ... # might be nice to have a function for defining a single model
        models.append(model)
    top_level_inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input((64, 64))
    x = model[0](top_level_inputs) # using functional model format here
    # if you want different parts of the input to go to different models, you may struggle.
    # Look into strided_slice if necessary
    for mod in models:
        x = mod(x) # you will need to code the true tree structure here, rather than this one-level for loop
    total_model = tf.keras.models.Model(top_level_inputs, x)
    return total_model

my_model = create_model(my_depth)
```

The biggest challenge will be automating the shapes if you don't have each layer get the same sized inputs, and making some sort of nested for-loop to handle the recursions/splitting.

Comment: Let me know if that helps, or if I am missing something!